# Last chunk of data truncated on arduino serial data

Tags: arduino, serial-communication

I have an arduino taking serial input and will turn on the leds. The code is below.

I have a strange problem that when I send multiples of 120x bytes e.g., 240, 480 the last 120 bytes never get read completely.

I see on the serial monitor 120 120 120 81 if I send 480 bytes of data. Could anyone point out the mistake?

```
#include "FastLED.h"
#define DATA_PIN 6
#define NUM_LEDS 40

byte colors[120];

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

void setup(){
  FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, DATA_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop(){
  if (Serial.available()){
    int i =0;
    char incomingByte;

    while(1) {  
      incomingByte = Serial.readBytes((char *)colors,120);
      break;
    }
    Serial.print(incomingByte);
    for(i=0;i<NUM_LEDS ;i++){
      leds[i].green = colors[i];
      leds[i].red = colors[i+1];
      leds[i].blue = colors[i+2];
    }
    if(incomingByte==0x78){
      FastLED.show();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is flawed in different ways.

First, please remove the useless use of `while(1) {…; break;}`, it's just adding an overhead and adds nothing to your algorithm.

Otherwise, your code is not working well because, I guess, at some point there's a lag happening in the serial communication that causes the read to timeout. Let's have a look at source code.

First, you take the [`readBytes()`](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Stream.cpp#L217) function. All it does is:

```
size_t Stream::readBytes(char *buffer, size_t length)
{
  size_t count = 0;
  while (count < length) {
    int c = timedRead();
    if (c < 0) break;
    *buffer++ = (char)c;
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

i.e. it iterates `length` times over the blocking read function. But it breaks if that function's return value is less than zero, returning less than `length` bytes. So that what's happening to get less than `length`, so let's have a look at [`timedRead()`](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Stream.cpp#L30):

```
int Stream::timedRead()
{
  int c;
  _startMillis = millis();
  do {
    c = read();
    if (c >= 0) return c;
  } while(millis() - _startMillis < _timeout);
  return -1; // -1 indicates timeout
}
```

what happens here, is that if the read succeeds, it returns the read value, otherwise it loops until timeout has passed, and returns -1, which will end `readBytes` immediately. The default value for the timeout is [1000ms](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Stream.h#L53), though you can make that value higher by using `Serial.setTimeout(5000);` in your `setup()` function.

Though you have nothing to earn by using the blocking `readBytes()` function. So you'd better instead write your loop so you read the values, and trigger an event only once all values have been read:

```
#define NB_COLORS 120

void loop() {
    static byte colors[NB_COLORS];
    static int colors_index=0;
    if (colors_index < NB_COLORS) {
        // let's read only one byte
        colors[colors_index] = Serial.read();
        // if a byte has been read, increment the index
        if (colors[colors_index] != -1)
            ++colors_index;
    } else {
        // reset the index to start over
        colors_index = 0;
        // should'nt you iterate 3 by 3, i.e. having i=i+3 instead of i++ ?
        for(i=0;i<NUM_LEDS ;i++){
          leds[i].green = colors[i];
          leds[i].red = colors[i+1];
          leds[i].blue = colors[i+2];
        }
        FastLED.show();
    } 
}
```

HTH

Comment: I get the idea but how does it work well for the first chunk it only gets corrupted for the last chunk. Also you are right when you say there is a timing issue. When I remove the Fastled.show() it reads perfectly well. I think the problem comes from show function but I don't understand how it reads the 3 chunks correctly but spoils the 4th one. (If I send 4)

Comment: I got your code to work and there was a small part that needed to be fixed if (colors[colors_index] != -1) wont work because its a byte array. It has to be casted to int So if anyone bumps into this they know. Thanks